# GPS not working on some phones

Tags: android, android-studio, gps, android-location, android-gps

Trying to get location with the following method. I have tested this method with various devices.

This code works for: **Huawei P20PRO**, **Samsung S6 edge plus**, **Xiaomi redmi 5**. 
It doesn't works with Xiaomi mi 5, it seems the code cant get his position.. Someone know why ?

```
public void getLocation() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission
                (this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ZonaStudenti.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_LOCATION);

        }
        else {
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            Location location1 = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            Location location2 = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager. PASSIVE_PROVIDER);
            /*location_func(location);*/


            if (location != null) {
                double latti = location.getLatitude();
                double longi = location.getLongitude();
                lattitude = String.valueOf(latti);
                longitude = String.valueOf(longi);
                latdaPass=latti;
                longdaPass=longi;

                try{
                    Geocoder geocoder=new Geocoder(this);
                    List<Address> adresses=null;

                    adresses=geocoder.getFromLocation(latti,longi,1);
                    String country=adresses.get(0).getCountryName();
                    String city=adresses.get(0).getLocality();
                    String Indirizzo = adresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
                    //citta.setText("Country: "+ country +"\n"+ "City: "+city);
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Country: "+ country +"\n"+ "City: "+city + "\n" + "Indirizzo: " + Indirizzo ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }catch (IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error" + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            else  if (location1 != null)
            {
                double latti = location1.getLatitude();
                double longi = location1.getLongitude();
                lattitude = String.valueOf(latti);
                longitude = String.valueOf(longi);
                latdaPass=latti;
                longdaPass=longi;
            }
            else  if (location2 != null)
            {
                double latti = location2.getLatitude();
                double longi = location2.getLongitude();
                lattitude = String.valueOf(latti);
                longitude = String.valueOf(longi);
                latdaPass=latti;
                longdaPass=longi;
            }
            else{

                Toast.makeText(this,"Non trovo la posizione",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }`
```

Comment: i had the same problem i solved by using this librabry
https://github.com/mohanmanu484/Location-track-library

Comment: @nik I will try it and let u know..